# Mezuzah on a Two-Room Bathroom

Tags: halacha, mezuzah, bathroom, architecture-design

This question is a bit complicated:
Let's say I have a two-room bathroom. The first room is a room with sinks and mirrors and the second room has the actual toilets. The first room and second room are connected by a door. The first room has another door that leads out into the corridor.

Should I put a mezuzah on the doorpost connecting the first room (room with sinks) to the corridor?

Why or why not?

Comment: FWIW the Yeshiva Ktana of Passaic has mezuzos on the outer doors in such an arrangement.

Comment: FWIW in my parent's house there is no Mezuza on the doorpost in this exact situation.

Comment: FWIW in Yeshivat Kol Torah they did not have Mezuzos on the outer doors in a similar arrangement; sort of "F" shaped, with the first right-arm being the sinks and the second right-arm being the toilets. Neither the outer door nor the sink area had a Mezuza, but Rav Neuwirth זצ"ל said we could say Brachot in the first room.

Answer (score 8):

In Shulchan Aruch ([YD Siman 286:4](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x6801)) it says that a bathroom and bathhouse etc. are exempt from Mezuzah because they are not made for Diras Kavod (respectable living quarters). In Shu"t Minchas Yitzchok ([4:89-90](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14681&st=&pgnum=490)) he adds that if they (bathroom etc.) are not used for anything that would obligate them to have a Mezuzah (i.e. some people use a bathroom to store things therein) then even the outer room is exempt from a Mezuzah.

See all this in Sefer Chovas Hador ([Perek 2:9-10 and footnote 37](https://www.otzar.org/wotzar/book.aspx?53220)).

Answer (score 0):

One has to ascertain the correct size of this "powder room".  I believe that if it is less than 4 amot x 4 amot (which is approx. 6 ft. x 6 ft.), it may be exempt from Mezuza, regardless of whether it is a room "ra'ui' (fit) for mezuzah.  Best to measure and check with your L.O.R.

Comment: Rooms under a certain size are exempt anyway (whether bathrooms, closets, entryways, or whatever).  I think this question is about bathrooms where the outer room is larger than that, which I've definitely seen in some reception halls, hotels, and schools.