# Does a storage room require a mezuzah?

Tags: halacha, mezuzah

Does a storage room require a mezuzah? For example, if someone has a storage unit detached from their house where they store tools and/or Passover utensils, would it require a mezuzah? And furthermore, should one make a beracha? Want to know what it depends on to present my questions to a Rav.

Comment: https://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Mezuzah#Closets.2C_Pantries.2C_and_Storage_Rooms https://www.halacha2go.com/blog/tx00169/

Comment: Somewhat related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/19085/mezuzah-for-room-used-by-non-jews https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/29363/mezuzah-on-a-two-room-bathroom  https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/57565/mezuzah-in-the-work-place

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three conditions are mentioned by the Acharonim:

1. How frequent one enters the storage house/room
2. Its location (nearby or attached to the home or not)
3. Its size (4*4 *amos* or *kdei lerabea*)

Rabbi Reuvain Mendlowitz authored an article about this:
https://vaadmhk.org/does-a-storage-room-require-a-mezuzah/

Answer (score 0):

A [duplicate question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/124107/does-a-large-storeroom-require-a-mezuza-according-to-the-sefardi-mizrachi-ruling) asks about the *halacha* according to *Sefaradim*.

[Halachipedia](https://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Mezuzah#Closets.2C_Pantries.2C_and_Storage_Rooms) brings some relevant sources

> The Gemara Yoma 11a cites a dispute between Rav Kahana and Rav Yehuda
> if a storage room needs a mezuzah if it isn't used for anything else.
> Rav Kahana held that this was a dispute in the tenayim. The Rif
> (Mezuzah 6b) and Rosh (Mezuzah no. 15) hold that it is obligated,
> while the Rambam Mezuzah 6:7 holds it is not.
>
> **[Shulchan Aruch YD
> 286:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.286.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) accepts the opinion of the Rif. Yalkut Yosef YD 285:30
> writes that one should put up a mezuzah without a bracha.** There are
> a number of Acharonim who suggest that it is best to avoid making a
> beracha since there are Rishonim who rule that a storage room does not
> require a mezuzah at all.

Similarly OU Kosher [writes](https://oukosher.org/halacha-yomis/i-have-a-large-storage-area-where-i-store-my-sukkah-i-enter-this-room-only-a-few-times-a-year-does-it-require-a-mezuzah/)

> Yalkut Yosef (Sova Semachot 1 – Mezuzah 37) writes that although there
> is a custom not to put a mezuzah on a seldom used storage room, **it is
> proper to be stringent and put up a mezuzah without a bracha.**

Comment: The current question also asks about sefardim. And ashkenazim.

Comment: There is a famous joke about Albert Einstein giving the same test two years in a row. To students wondering he answered "The questions are the same but the answers are different". As you know the same is true at times between *Sefaradim* and *Ashkenazim*.

Comment: I'm just saying you don't have to motivate posting sefardic sources by appealing to any special request. Just post it proudly.