# Does a large storeroom require a mezuza according to the Sefardi/Mizrachi ruling?

Tags: halacha, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, mezuzah

Question relates to apartment in Israel with maksan - מחסן (store room) on a different floor than the apartment.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Yohanon and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: I wrote an answer for you according to Sefaradim but put in [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/124109/11501) on the duplicate question